# How to use getContentResolver().query for file?

Tags: java, android

I have one `java.io.File` pointed to `/storage/files/pic.jpg` (for brevity) called `mFile`

When I try to query for the file using

```
Uri photoUri = Uri.fromFile(mFile);
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);
```

`cursor` ends up null, would expect `cursor` not not be null.

`photoUri.to_String` returns `file:///storage/files/pic.jpg`

I know the file exists, since i can load it with

```
 BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

or open an InputStream with the same Uri

```
 InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
```

I get the feeling that photoUri is malformed somehow, I have seen posts saying it should be `content://...`, but they also refers to obsolete versions of the android sdk.

Comment: What you want is impossible as you cannot change a file system path in a content path without providing a content resolver who serves that file first. But why would you? And what do you want to query that the File class cannot tell you?

Comment: What i want to get is the Image-files orientation. This was a close as i got to a solution

Comment: You are very far away from that in this way i think. Better use the ExifInterface class for that.

Comment: Yeah, maybe so. But cannot find a proper example for this

Comment: Then search again. I saw so many ExifInterface posts on this site ....

Comment: Will do, will leave the question here so that others doesnt fall into this trap. Thanks